# Why after linking to Form the data doesn't transfer from Form2 to Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to do a big coding project however I hit a wall.
I need to show the name and score once the data has been entered in.
I tried using youtube tutorials, classes for the code. But no such luck.
Any help would be great!

`form1`:

```
private void bNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    score link = new score();
    link.Show();

    SudentBox.Items.Clear();
}
```

`form2`:

```
public object StudentBox { get; private set; }

private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();

    try
    {
        string name = txtName.Text;
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
        txtStoreScores.Text += score.ToString() + " ";
    }
    catch (Exception x) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number");
    }
}

private void bClearScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtScore.Text = "";
    txtStoreScores.Text = "";
}
```

Examples of what the forms should look like with the final result.

[image: form1]

[image: form 2]

Comment: I have no idea what "linking data to form means", but there is such a thing as DataBinding - if the 2 forms share the same datasource, data added in one form is automagically available in the other.  No luck required.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using the property.
Add public static property on Form 2 and set the values of the text to the property respectively and then access them on the Form 1.

On Form 2 in the Ok button click event do this

```
public static string Name { get; set; }
public static string Scores { get; set; }
private void bOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Name = txtName.Text;
   Scores = txtStoreScores.TextBox;
}
```

Then in the Form 1 OnLoad event access those properties and display them in the TextBox

```
private Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StudentBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", Form2.Name, Form2.Scores);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add the get and set for a property.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you are trying to code a form of `DialogBox`.
 
Say, you want to get a name from the dialog (e.g. from a `TextBox` in `Form2`), you can have a model like this (in `Form2` of course).

```
public string Name
{
    //where myTextBox is the design name of your textbox
    get => myTextBox.Text;
    set => myTextBox.Text=value;
}
```

**Simple Ok Button**

```
public void OkBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Now, you need to actually get this info to display in your `Form1`. That is easy.
Just like you have started above:

```
private void bNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    score link = new score();
    link.ShowDialog();
    //Note that you won't be able to access form1.
    SudentBox.Items.Clear();
    //You can now get the name
    string _nameResult=link.Name;
    NameTextbox.Text=_nameResult;
}
```

I hope this gets you started!